# Empathy with Facebook on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, empathy, facebook

I have read many questions about Empathy and Facebook and everyone says that it is not possible to connect them, but just a few weeks ago, suddenly it started to work. I have found other people too who say that they can use Empathy with Facebook. But yesterday I had to reinstall Ubuntu and now Empathy has stopped working.

How can I make it to work again?

I'm a Linux noob, I've used Ubuntu for 2 months and am still not sure what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

this currently is not available (to my knowledge) since FB has disabled their XMPP support, for a new chat protocol (which empathy does not support).

Pidgin, another chat client, can connect with FB messages through the use of [purple-facebook](https://github.com/jgeboski/purple-facebook/wiki), an external plugin. In order to support FB on Empathy, someone would have to likely port this functionality to Empathy. Unfortunately, Empathy has no plugin manager, so it is unlikely anyone will do this.